# Passing props to RN components using a for loop and a list

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am pretty new to React Native and React in general so excuse me if I am missing some core concept on how to do what I am trying. I have two components, a ScrollView component which will be populated with my VendorListing component. Inside the ScrollView is a for loop which iterates through a list for every element of that list and passes the value of that element to my VendorListing component.I want my VendorListing components to render within the ScrollView with their respective data that was passed to them as a prop.

Below is my code for the ScrollView, I have a list with all of the info that I need and for loop that passes that data to the VendorListing

```
var listingContent = [
    {
        title: 'Dentist',
        desc: 'This is generic dentist listing',
        add:'1455 Gerrard St. Toronto, ON',
        imgURI: '140x100.png',
        srtHr: '0800',
        clsHr: '1800',
    },
    {   
        title: 'Dentist 2',
        desc: 'This is generic dentist listing',
        add:'350 Kipling Ave. Toronto, ON',
        imgURI: '140x100.png',
        srtHr: '0800',
        clsHr: '1700',
    },
    {
        title: 'Physiotherapist',
        desc: 'This is generic physiotherapist listing',
        add:'1200 Yonge St. Toronto, ON',
        imgURI: '140x100.png',
        srtHr: '1000',
        clsHr: '2100',
    },
    {
        title: 'Barber',
        desc: 'This is generic barber listing',
        add:'985 Eglinton Ave. Toronto, ON',
        imgURI: '140x100.png',
        srtHr: '0900',
        clsHr: '2100',
    }
];
export default class ScrollViewListing extends Component{
    render(){
        var lst=[];
        j = listingContent.length;
        for(i=0;i<j;i++){
            lst.push(<VendorListing 
                info={listingContent.indexOf(i)}/>);
        };
        return(
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    {lst}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Following that is my code for the VendorListing component where I try to render it with the data that is passed in.

```
class VendorListing extends Component{
    render(){
        var info = this.props.info;
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.imageBox}>
                    <Image 
                        source={{}}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.content}>
                    <View style={styles.content1}>
                        <Text>{this.props.info}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.props.info}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.content2}>
                        <Text> Address</Text>
                        <Text>Open to Close</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am passing the props in the correct fashion, whenever I try to render the VendorListing component using a reference to this.prop.info I end up with an error saying that variable does not exist

```
<Text>{this.props.info.title}</Text>
<Text>{this.props.info.desc}</Text>
```

will result in the app crashing with the message

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.info.title/desc')

I should note, I can render my VendorListing components within the ScrollView no problem by placing any static text within the fields of the VendorListing component, the crashes and failures only occur when I try to reference the props I am passing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a for loop rendered in a ScrollView since you have RN FlatList which do that for you and is better to improve performances because it renders only the items which are visible on the screen. (See [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) and https://whatdidilearn.info/2018/12/09/react-native-how-to-use-flatlist.html)

For your bug, you'r calling `listingContent.indexOf(i)`, which only return the index of the element, not the element itself. You should call `listingContent[listingContent.indexOf(i)]` which can be simplified by `listingContent[i]` if you want it to work.

Comment: Note that he's doing `listingContent.indexOf(i)` that returns `-1` in the array he posted as example as it wont find the `indexOf` a number

Comment: As you mentioned, I found an example using FlatList and it is much better and I got it working just as I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
export default class ScrollViewListing extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <ScrollView>
           {listingContent.map(info => (
             <VendorListing info={info} />
           ))}
         </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: As [@Bastien Naiiru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8270510/bastien-naiiru) mentions, it would be better to use a `FlatList` instead.